# C++11 Lock free update 2 variables atomically

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, compare-and-swap

I'd like to update `atomicX` when a thread finds a new minimum to change it to. When it does set the new minimum, I would also like to change a variable `y`, atomically. Is there a way to do this without locks?

Example of a thread function executing on many threads at once:

```
uint64_t x = atomicX;
int y = g();

for(int newX = 0; newX < x; ++newX)
{
    if(f(newX))
    {
        while(newX < x && !atomicX.compare_exchange_strong(x, newX));
        // also set atomicY to y if the exchange happened above
        break;
    }

    x = atomicX;
}
```

I can do it with locks as so:

```
int y = g();

for(uint64_t newX = 0; newX < atomicX; ++newX)
{
    if(f(newX))
    {
        mutex.lock();
        if(newX < atomicX)
        {
            atomicX = newX;
            atomicY = y; // atomicY no longer needs to be atomic
        }
        mutex.unlock()
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm also open to any cleaner structuring of this, or another way to do it all together. I don't like that I have to have the same `newX < x` condition twice, or that I have to break the loop.

Comment: Have you something like `struct s { int x; int y; }; std::atomic<s>`? [It might very well be lock-free](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0eb0b67742805375) for your platform.

Comment: @dyp I ruled it out because I assumed it wouldn't be lock free. This is ultimately going on multiple platforms and I would rather have something I could reasonably assume will be lock free on all platforms (like atomic<int>)

Comment: Only `std::atomic_flag` is guaranteed to be lock-free on *all* platforms.

Comment: @dyp I don't need a real guarantee, just a strong "it should be lock free on anything modern"

Comment: On "anything modern" `int` is 32 bits and pointers are 64 bits. I'd be surprised if `std::atomic` was not lock-free for both `void*` and `struct { int x; int y; };`.

Comment: @Casey I actually need a `uint64_t and a uint32_t`, minimally.

Comment: @Dave Could you clarify the entire problem? I think I have a handle but I'm not sure. You have some search space which is the domain of X. You have to perform some calculation on X to determine if it is a candidate. Your final goal is then to minimize the candidate X. Where does Y fit in? Why does it need to be updated when X changes? Does it affect `f(newX)`? If your goal is to select the minimal candidate X, can you not calculate Y after having found the minimal candidate X?

Comment: Also, in your first code sample, I think you have a bug:  `while(newX < x && !atomicX.compare_exchange_strong(x, newX));` - I think you meant to compare `while( newX < atomicX && ... )`. `newX` and `x` are both local variables to that function, and you already just checked that `newX < x` in your for loop condition when you began that iteration. Your statement `while( newX < x && ... )` is equivelent to `while( true && ... )`

Comment: Dave, can you just edit your type requirements into the question? It isn't clear which of x,y is the uint64_t, and which is the uit32_t (in case it matters)

Comment: @antiduh `compare_exchange_strong` will update `x` when it returns false. So on the first iteration of that loop, you're right, it's `true && ...`, but on subsequent iterations the first condition has meaning. I think I'm doing it correctly for that loop, but correct me if I'm still wrong

Comment: @Dave Ah, yes, you are right.

Comment: @antiduh To answer your first question, think of `y` as an id. I do need to find the minimum `x` when some criteria is met, and I need to know both what the minimum is, and which id it corresponds to. I can't calculate it afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fairly simply and likely-to-be-portable-enough solution, which is to use a pointer and CAS that:

```
struct XY {
  uint64_t x;
  uint32_t y;
};
std::atomic<XY *> globalXY;
```

Then the tricky bit becomes figuring out how to allocate and release these objects without excessive cost or ABA problems.

For clarity, the code would end up something like this:

```
XY *newXY = somehow_allocate_objects();
XY *oldXY = globalXY;
int oldX = oldXY->x;
newXY->y = g();

for(int newX = 0; newX < oldX; ++newX) {
    if(f(newX)) {
        // prepare newXY before swapping
        newXY->x = newX;
        while(newX < oldX && !globalXY.compare_exchange_strong(oldXY, newXY)) {
            // oldXY was updated, reload oldX
            oldX = oldXY->x;
        }
        // globalXY->x,y both updated by pointer CAS
        break;
    }
    oldXY = globalXY;
    oldX = oldXY->x;
}
```

---

For reference, the eventual conclusion was that these threads were long-lived, so statically allocating a single `XY` instance for each thread was sufficient.

Comment: But if I did the `compare_exchange_strong` on an a pointer I'm just comparing pointers, when I want to compare `x`.

Comment: You asked to _change_ x and y atomically. By swapping the pointer, you change the x and y (it points to) atomically.

Comment: Uhh, well as the code in the question shows, I do need to change x and y atomically, but only when a new x is less than atomicX.

Comment: Do you need to handle the case where some other thread is mutating atomicX during your loop? Because you're not comparing `newx < atomicX`, you're comparing your local cache `x` of `atomicX`, and that doesn't obviously need to change ...

Comment: I know I'm comparing to the local cache of `x`, but that's intentional. `compare_exchange_strong` will update `x` if it returns false, and it will only swap is `x` == `atomicX`

Comment: ok, adapted your original code to my suggestion so you can see what I mean. You still haven't explained if oldX will really have changed in the meantime btw - we could probably do better than this if you'd clarify your threading behaviour

Comment: Yes oldX could definitely change during the loop because of a different thread. That's kind of the whole point of having the `compare_exchange` and the local cached `x` at all. In fact all CAS loops are basically set up with this compare with a cached version and then only perform the swap if the cached variable still equals the atomic value. Otherwise, I would've just written `if(f(newX) && newX < atomicX){ atomicX = newX; atomixY = newY; }` right? The thread function examples up there are the only things modifying atomicX - just pretend that function is running as 15 threads.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57568/discussion-between-useless-and-dave).